# Can I find variable's references and its mapping's references in C#/VS2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Often times, when I need to make changes to a variable, I need to know how my changes will impact the code downstream. I would normally do so by right-clicking on the variable, clicking on "*Find All References*", and analyze the downstream code. Often times the value of that reference gets copied (ie: mapped) to another variable, and then I would have to repeat the same process of right-clicking on that mapped variable, clicking on "Find All References", and analyze more downstream code. This same process can be repeated several times.

Is there a framework/extension that allows me to find all **references** and its **mapping's references** in ***one*** user action (ie: a button that says "*Find All References and Mappings*")?

Let's say I have the following classes/interface

```
public class Order {
   public int Id {set; get;}
   ...
}

public class ICreateOrder {
   int OrderId {set; get;}
   ...
}

public class CreateOrder : ICreateOrder {
   public int OrderId {set; get;}
   ...
}
```

It would be awesome if I can right-click on `Order.Id`, click on "Find All References and Mappings" and VS2019 would effectively give me all references of `Order.Id`, `ICreateOrder.OrderIdId` and `CreateOrder.OrderId` in one go.

Comment: Can you make your code sample complete, so we can see what you mean with 'mapping'? Please add the code of the getters and setters, now it doesn't make a lot of sense to me since there's no relationship whatsoever between Id and OrderId.

Comment: There is no relation between `Order.Id` and `ICreateOrder.OrderId` or `CreateOrder.OrderId`.

Comment: As an alternative to the solution that you're looking for, you could [create a strongly-typed OrderId](https://andrewlock.net/using-strongly-typed-entity-ids-to-avoid-primitive-obsession-part-1/). Then have all Order classes use this object for the ID. This would allow you to find all references of that ID object across the different Order objects

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes @stijn There isn't a relationship in my example (eg: Order -> Product relationship) but getting a list of a relationships would still be helpful imo. 

Let's say I want to change the `Id` type from an `int` to a `Guid`. Before I would consider such a change, I would investigate where the identity of orders are being used. My proposed "Find All References and Mappings" would help with that.

Another example is let's say I have a Person class with a property FullName, and I decide to split FullName into FirstName, MiddleName, and LastName. Again this would help.

Comment: Just temporarily change the type, you should get a lot of compiling errors showing you where this change impacts.

Comment: @devNull that would be a good idea if I just needed this feature for entity Ids. Applying a similar pattern to all of my properties (non-Ids) would significantly introduce a lot more code than I would want to write.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes That change would not necessarily create a compilation error. what if `Create.OrderId` is never assigned by `Order.Id`? What if `Create.OrderId` is assigned via HTTP request? Changing Order's Id type would not show a compilation error that mentions `CreateOrder.OrderId`

Comment: I know my example doesn't make the mapping between `Order.Id`, `ICreateOrder.OrderId` and `CreateOrder.OrderId` explicit but I wouldn't mind making it explicit via code, sort of how Automapper does it.

Comment: How should a tool (Visual Studio or an extension) know that `Create.OrderId` is assigned via HTTP request (or automapper)? Tools can only do a static code analysis as the compiler does.

Comment: I didn't want to assume/suggest a solution but since you have asked. A developer can explicitly map properties using C# attributes, similar to how Automapper does it (see SourceMember in https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Attribute-mapping.html). A static analysis tools can use something like Roselyn to parse the code and return the mappings..

Answer (score 0):

Use the find feature in visual studio. It's pretty powerful.

Just do Ctrl+Shift+F and type `\..*Id` into Find what: field and pick the scope of the search to be Entire Solution in Look in: field...

You need to check Match case and use regex expressions in Find options section.

You might also get some extras but for sure you won't miss any of your references.

Comment: This is an alternative that I have used in the past but sifting through the 'extra' false-positive results has become an annoyance for me, especially when I work with large unfamiliar codebases.